# Unable to run Pub/Sub emulator on Docker in M2 Mac

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I recently got an M2 Mac and have been unable to run Pub/Sub Emulator on it. I was using the following code previously:

```
def create_topic(project_id, publisher, topic):
    print("I am here 7.1")
    publisher = PublisherClient()
    print("I am here 7.2")
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic)
    print("I am here 7.3")
    new_topic = publisher.create_topic(request={"name": topic_path})
    print(f"Created topic: {new_topic.name}")
    return topic_path
```

When I run this, "I am here 7.3" is the last line printed. Then it just gets stuck without printing any errors. The image also has the AMD64 warning which is why I think this issue has something to do with M2 laptops. It works fine on intel ones.

Edit: The AMD64 warning I see against this container in docker desktop:
[image]

When I hover over the warning it says:

> Image may have poor performance, or fail, if run via Emulation.

Comment: Can you please provide the error? The error is when you start up the emulator or when you run the above code (the code isn't running the emulator; it is trying ot create a topic).

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn At first there is no output and then after waiting for a couple of minutes it outputs google.api_core.exceptions.DeadlineExceeded: 504 Deadline Exceeded.

Comment: "The image also has the AMD64 warning." Where is this warning coming from?

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn The warning is on Docker Desktop. I'll attach a screenshot on my question.